# how i can focus on the return form that have validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application , and i have the following contact us form at the middle of the contact Us view:-

```
 <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
                    <h2>Contact Us1</h2>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @if (TempData["message"] != null)
                    {

                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>

                            <strong> @TempData["message"].</strong>

                        </div>
                    }
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            <hr />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) <span style="color:red">*</span>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @cols = 60, rows = 10, @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" /><span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
                                        <img src="~/img/ajax-loader.gif" />

                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

and here the Get and Post action methods:-

```
 public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
            ViewBag.Description = "Home";

            return View();
        }
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Contact(Contact c)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        //code goes here
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Your Feedback has been submitted. Thanks");
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot submit you Contact Form, please review the Contact Form for any missing info.");
    return View(c);

}
```

now i am facing this problem:-
1. since the contact us form appear on the middle of the page, so users on small sized screens , might submit the form , then the Post request failed (model validation failed), where the contact us form will be rendered again with the validation errors shown, but users might not see the form, since by default the browser will move to the top. while on large screen the user can still see the form , but on mobile browser users might miss that there are errors on the form that they have just submit.

so i am thinking if there is a way to do this:-

1. if the form is rendered with errors, to force the browser (using jquery form example) to go to the form , so that users can see the validation errors ?
   can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: You can use a bit of javascript/jquery to scroll to the form when the page first loads - but do you want to do this always, or just when you return the view because of a `ModelState` error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to move the focus on the form only when there are validation errors..thanks

Comment: If you must use javascript then why not keep it simple and just use client side validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you `@Html.ValidationSummary()` code should be inside the form tags in order for it to work correctly.

You can use javascript to scroll to the form in the view. Give the form (or an element near where you want to scroll to) an `id` attribute

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
```

Then add the following script (inside document.ready)

```
if ('@ViewBag.HasError') {
    location.href = '#form'; // or location.hash = '#form';
}
```

and modify the POST method to add the `ViewBag` property if there are errors

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot ..... info.");
ViewBag.HasError = true; // add this
return View(c)
```

Side note: Not tested, but you should also be able to use

```
if ('@ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Any()') {
```

as an alternative to using a `ViewBag` property.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try your approach,,, but i have one question you mentioned that i need to have the @Html.ValidationSummary() code inside the form tags for it to work correctly,,But in my current  case I am placing it outside the form tag it is working well , i mean it will show any model errors ,same as when it is inside the form tag ..

Comment: In you case it will work because you have set the `true` parameter (i.e. for displaying model level errors only) but if you were to display all errors then it would not work correctly so its always best to put it inside the form tags

Comment: @StephenMuecke now i define this Html.ValidationSummary(false, "error occured", new { class = "text-danger" }) out side the form tag and it worked as expected.. although i search the web for this and many users were mentioning that they will get error that the Html.ValidationSummary() need to be defined inside a form tag as follow http://forums.asp.net/t/1354777.aspx?+ValidationSummary+must+be+placed+inside+a+form+tag+with+runat+server+ but this is not the case in my current project..now i am using mvc 5.2 maybe this is fixed on this mvc version,, not sure...

Comment: @MathewHellums, Because the code in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` searches for a form, and only if it finds one will it wire up the rules for `jquery.validate.js` (as I noted to johnG, it could be outside the form in this case, but its always best to put it inside so cleint side validation is also wire up)

Comment: @johnG. Not sure why you would want `@Html.ValidationSummary(false);` - you then display the error messages twice. Since you have added a model level error in the POST method, that will be displayed so the user sees a message that something is invalid so they would then continue to scroll down and see and specific errors associated with each control. Seems odd that you would want to display them twice especially when the whole purpose of this is to handle the view on small screens.

Comment: Note also that if you do want it outside the form then you should probably have (say) `<div id="error">@Html.ValidationSummary(....)</div>` and change the script to `location.href = '#error';`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did so for testing purposes only,,, because you mentioned that if i pass false then i need to place the html.validationsummary inside the form tag... i did this test since i find it a good approach to place the Html.ValidationSummary(true, "error.", new { class = "alert alert-danger" }) at the top of the page (out side the form tag) but not sure if this is a valid approach or i need to keep the Html.ValidationSummary inside the form tag ?

Comment: Not strictly necessary in your case because you have `@Html.ValidationMessage()` elements associated with the controls. But I thought the whole purpose of this was to improve the UI so the user did not have to scroll - If you put it inside the form and use the script in my answer, the page is scrolled to the form and the user sees the model level error and can start editing the form controls without the need to then scroll down to them

Comment: The purpose is to inform users of any errors without them having to scroll to find out.

Comment: Which is exactly what my code does - If you put the `ValidationSummary()` method at the top of the screen, then if you return the view the user then has to scroll down to the form. But if you put it inside the form, then the page is already scrolled to the form so the user sees the general error message and does not need to scroll (because they are already in the form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the reply .. now i tried your approach but seems checking this inside the script "If ('@ViewBag.HasError')" will always pass regardless of the ViewBag.HasError value.

Comment: I assume you are then also setting `ViewBag.HasError=false;` (which you should not be - only set the value if there is an error - because the `if` clause is checking that a (any) value has been provided).

Answer (score 1):

Put `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` at the top of your page. Change true to false to show all property level errors.

Comment: property level will be shown even when validationsumamry is set to true.. these two settings are not related... setting validationsummary to false means that property level will be shown twice one the summary and beside the related fields...

Comment: Of course the individual validation messages will render regardless of what you pass into ValidationSummary.  I was referring to the validation summary and that it would output property level errors if you pass in false.

Comment: but should the Html.ValidationSummary be inside the form tag , or i can place it at the top of the page outside the form tag ?

Comment: It will render regardless of where you put it.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: ValidationSummary simply "returns an unordered list (ul element) of validation messages that are in the ModelStateDictionary object." Verbatim from MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx

Comment: yes i tired it and it worked well,,, but not sure if there are any hidden errors if i place it out side the form tag ,,, now i find these 2 links which mention that the html.validationsummary need to be defined inside a form tag otherwise i should get errors http://codeverge.com/asp.net.mvc/html.validationsummary-needs-form-specific-scopin/49100 & http://forums.asp.net/t/1354777.aspx?+ValidationSummary+must+be+placed+inside+a+form+tag+with+runat+server+ but this is not the case inside my asp.net mvc5.2 project

Comment: Those refer to webforms. And there is no such thing as hidden errors.  You've proven it works.  If it's what you want then go ahead and use it.